# Issue with Spring Scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using the below code I am trying to set the value for request attribute "name" to object Text. When request attribute name = Test2 , I introduce a delay of 10 seconds. I fire off a request with name = Test2. When the request is progress , I fire off another request with a name = Test. For the second request I see name = Test getting printed and not Test1 , since I guess the bean Text is a singleton. When I update scope("prototype") in Text class, I see the value of Text.getData() in DemoRestController.java is null. How can I define the scope of Text object as prototype and autowire it in DemoRestController?

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
@ImportResource("application-context.xml")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DemoRestController.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoRestController {

    @Autowired
    Text text;
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {

        if(text.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("Test2")){
            System.out.println("Matching!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(name + " = " + text.getData());
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**Greeting.java**

```
package com.example;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**GreetingInterceptor.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class GreetingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    @Autowired
    Text text;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" Intecepted :: " + request.getParameter("name"));
        text.setData(request.getParameter("name"));
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(request, response, handler);
    }





}
```

**Text.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Text {

    private String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }



}
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- <import resource = "classpath:config.xml"/>  -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder/>
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.comcast.customer.db" /> -->
    <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:customer-config.properties" />-->

    <!-- <bean id="billingConnector"
        class="com.comcast.billing.connector.app.BillingConnector"/> -->
    <!-- <bean id="LocationServiceConnector"
        class="com.comcast.cx.LocationServiceConnector.LocationServiceConnector"/> -->
        <mvc:interceptors>
   <mvc:interceptor>
     <mvc:mapping path="/greeting/**" />
     <bean class="com.example.GreetingInterceptor" />
   </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: _I see the value of Text object autowired in DemoRestController.java is null_ How can you tell?

Comment: In Text.java , I added scope("prototype") , started the spring boot program and fired a rest request and I saw a nullpointerexception being printed in this line "if(text.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("Test2")){" present in DemoRestController

Comment: How do you know the getData() didn't return null? Please don't use [trainwrecks](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrainWreck)

Comment: I added these 2 lines to the code :      System.out.println(" Value of text = " + text);
     System.out.println(" Value of text.getData() = " + text.getData());                            I see the below being printed :  Value of text = com.example.Text@6fbe2f87
 Value of text.getData() = null

Comment: Sure , will avoid trainwrecks  in future. Thanks.

Comment: Why should `getData` return anything other than `null`? It seems from what you just posted that `getData` is the one returning `null`.

Comment: In the interceptor  , I am doing  text.setData(request.getParameter("name")). When I don't add the line scope("prototype") as posted  , I see getData returning value. But when I add scope("prototype") to the bean , I see getData() is null.

Comment: Why do you think the `Text` instance autowired in the interceptor is the same as the one autowired in the controller? You used `prototype`.

Comment: You seem to want `request` scope.

Comment: I have tried to build this example service to solve another issue with a larger REST service. In that service I get the headers in the request. I pass these headers to number of downstream calls that I make. All these calls are async calls. My service return a response immediately and this caused the request object to be lost. All the header data in request object is lost as well. I am trying to copy the header data into another bean which can retain the header data after the request object is closed.

Comment: I see that your main issue is that you're storing state in your singleton scoped beans. That will always lead to misbehaviour of the application. It will be way easier if you recover the `"test"` parameter from request in your interceptor rather than trying to springify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) about the `prototype` scope states

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
>   bean is made. That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you
>   request it through a `getBean()` method call on the container.

every `@Autowired` will result in a different instance.

The instance injected into your `GreetingInterceptor` is unrelated to the instance injected into your `DemoRestController`.

Use `request` scope if you want a single instance per request/response cycle.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios for clearing my understanding. Is there a way that you would recommend to retain the value in request scope after the response is returned ?

Comment: @PunterVicky There is no request scope once handling for the corresponding request has completed. Maybe you actually want `session` scope.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios , I do get the expected result when I used session scope as you suggested (@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS). The service that I expose is a REST service and there is no relation between different calls that we recieve (no concept of session as such). Are there any implications that I must analyze before proceeding this route? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: If you're not maintaining sessions, you'll be getting a new instance on every request, which is equivalent to `request` scope.

Comment: one last question - I assume the difference will be that request object will be lost whereas the session object will not be lost after the response is sent. Is my understanding correct? Won't session object be killed when request object is destroyed?

Comment: @PunterVicky RESTful services should be stateless, using session scope would be a bad practice in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi , sorry for extending this conversation. Is it possible to help in letting me know the implications of doing this?