# Session Scope in Restful Spring Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881789/issue-with-spring-scope/33882227#33882227). I have a Restful service that invokes a number of webservices in an async fashion (using threads - fire and forget). I pass the request headers received by my service down to these webservices. However since these requests are fired in an async manner , these typically execute after my REST service returns a response. This causes HTTP request object to be lost. Hence as suggested in this thread I am using session scope to retain the request headers. Will this have any adverse impact that I should analyze. Is there a better approach that I must look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start using session scope to store requests, your service is not RESTful anymore, because it's not stateless. I would suggest to avoid using session scope altogether.

If you need to use request object in asynchronous thread (using Spring's `@Async` annotation), just pass it to asynchronous logic via parameter.

Something like this:

```
@Component
public class AsyncUserService {

  @Async("customTaskExecutor")
  public void updateOrAddUser(int id, HttpServletRequest request) throws {
    //do your stuff
  }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
  private final AsyncUserService userService;

  @Autowired
  public UserController(AsyncUserService userService) {
    super();
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public void putUser(@PathVariable("id") int identifier, HttpServletRequest request) {
    userService.updateOrAddUser(identifier, request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks luboskrnac, I did use async annotation to trigger async requests , but the request context was being lost in the interceptors that intercepted the backend calls. I'll try again

Comment: I also have another question around this. In this scenario I am using session scoped bean to only retain the values for my async calls and not using it to make the service stateful. Please can you help in explaining the adverse impacts that this may cause? Thank you!

Comment: In your case it may not be issue, but using session scope when you simply can pass the request to the thread via parameter simply doesn't make sense to me. When I work on REST services, session scope is big exclamation mark during code review.